# Bean creation errors for request-scoped beans

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When a Spring bean is annotated with `SCOPE_REQUEST`, it is created and destroyed every time a HTTP request is received by the servlet. If this bean creation fails, a server error is sent back to the caller.

In this trivial example, the creation of the `MyInputs` bean is dependent on the contents of the HTTP request.

```java
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public MyInputs myInputs(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String header1 = request.getHeader("header1");
        if (header1 == null) {
            throw new MyException("header1 is missing");
        }
        return new MyInputs(header1);
    }
}
```

If the HTTP request does not contain a required header, a `BeanCreationException` will be thrown. This is translated into an unhelpful "500 Internal Server Error" response.

I would like to return a more user-friendly response code and body, for example, a "400 Bad Request" with a helpful message. How do I customize this response translation? I cannot find any lifecycle hooks which will allow this.

---

Note: This is how the request-scoped bean is consumed:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final Provider<MyInputs> myInputsProvider;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(Provider<MyInputs> myInputsProvider) {

        this.myInputsProvider = myInputsProvider;
    }

    @GetMapping("/do-stuff")
    public void doStuff() {

        // Get the inputs for the current request
        MyInputs myInputs = myInputsProvider.get();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just annotate your exception with a responsestatus, like this : 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception

Comment: @beatrice I did try that.. the problem is that Spring wraps everything into a `BeanCreationException`, so the usual handlers don't get triggered.

Comment: Please show how you're trying to use the `MyInputs` bean in your request handler.

Comment: Maybe use an interceptor that calls `MyInput.setHeader` after checking if its present that throws an exception elsewise. That exception won't get wrapped by spring. I would be very surprised to see such an `@Bean` function - a beans construction is normally not exceptional

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis added an example.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the `ExceptionHandler` expecting a `BeanCreationException` should work just fine. Please provide a [mcve] if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice` annotation in order to handle exceptions after are thrown.

Also you need to use `@ExceptionHandler` in order to handle the exception.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<CustomError> handleException(MyException ex, WebRequest request) {
        CustomError error = new CustomError();            
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        error.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Spring lifecycle wraps everything into a `BeanCreationException`. I haven't seen exception handlers getting triggered in that case, either with `@ExceptionHandler(BeanCreationException.class)` or with `@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)`.

Comment: Try it using @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) :) if you are in the request context then it should work.